How to add one day on JPA Query string - Hibernate 6.5.x
I've changed from Spring-Boot 3.1.4 to 3.3.0 and now one JPA Query that queries an Oracle database is not working anymore:
     @Query(value = """
     SELECT new
     ...
     LEFT JOIN cc.company com
     LEFT JOIN fpl.fileParameter fp
     LEFT JOIN fpl.person p
     WHERE fpl.actionTime 
      BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:endDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1
            AND at.id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            ORDER BY fpl.id DESC
    """)
    Page<LogForSendingParameterQuery> findLogForSendingParameter(String startDate, String endDate, Pageable pageable);
...

Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Operand of + is of type 'java.lang.Object' which is not a numeric type (it is not an instance of 'java.lang.Number', 'java.time.Temporal', or 'java.time.TemporalAmount')
I know that in this version Spring-Boot use Hibernate 6 and it is complaining about the operator +, but how can I add one day on a JPA Query string?

I think you'd better directly pass the parameters as Java dates, to avoid the casts. Also, BETWEEN works with strings so you don't need to cast to date if the strings are in a valid format. The + operator is still the way to go with Hibernate 6, this is not the problem, if you want to use only pure HQL maybe take a look at the cast() function. However as you already use TO_DATE which as far as I know is database specific, you could continue with Oracle specific functions.

Have you tried using INTERVAL '1' DAY?

I did as @Yann39 said and changed the parameter to LocalDateTime and passed Java date already adding one day to the endDate.
@Query(value = """
     SELECT new
     ...
     LEFT JOIN cc.company com
     LEFT JOIN fpl.fileParameter fp
     LEFT JOIN fpl.person p
     WHERE fpl.actionTime 
      BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
            AND at.id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            ORDER BY fpl.id DESC
    """)
Page<LogForSendingParameterQuery> findLogForSendingParameter(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate, Pageable pageable);

And added two methods to convert date from String to LocalDateTime and to add one day:
    @NotNull
    private static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime(String date) {
        return LocalDate.parse(date).atTime(ZERO, ZERO, ZERO);
    }

    @NotNull
    private static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimePlusOneDay(LocalDateTime date) {
        return date.plusDays(ONE_DAY);
    }


Instead of atTime(ZERO, ZERO, ZERO), you can use atStartOfDay() or atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).
